# Radial Slider - drawing trace

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making Radial Slider with HTML, CSS and JS.
It looks like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/b3k9hjLc/
My html is:

```
<div>
    <div id="rotationSliderContainer">
        <div id="rotationSlider"></div>
        <div id="rotationSliderDegrees">0&deg;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm having problem with drawing the trace of the slider (so, when I move the dot, the selected are has to change color)
Does anyonne has an idea how to do it?
Thank you.

Comment: There is a problem that the dot is not following the circle. But you have a lot of examples, such as: https://codepen.io/jon-walstedt/pen/qlofJ (quick search on Google)